# hibernate - lazy init joined component

Tags: java, hibernate

I used the mapping solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420531/mapping-hibernate-components-to-a-separate-table) to have a joined component. But it make hibernate trigger join query to obtain the component event i use fetch="select" in `<join>`

Please tell me how can i make the joined component lazy init.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `fetch="select"` you effectively switch off lazy loading. Have you tried without?