# Mapping hibernate components to a separate table using annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence

I have an embeddable component called Location that is mapped to an Event entity using Hibernate ORM. The schema uses the same column name ("id") and a shared key value for the event and location. Because the location is optional, I'd like to store it in a separate table (event_locations) but haven't been able to. How could this be accomplished with JPA annotations?

Related question using xml mapping [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420531/mapping-hibernate-components-to-a-separate-table?answertab=active#tab-top)